# Can a password be passed to SafeNet USB Token through iText or will the User always be prompted

Tags: itext, token

I am trying to use iText to specify a certification signature for Pdf documents that will automatically be verified (blue ribbon) within Adobe Reader.  In order for this to occur, the certificate used for signing must be recognized by Adobe as tying to a root certificate of an AATL member.  All AATL Certificate Authorities seem to deliver their certificates on a SafeNet USB Token.  The example Bruno gives in his "Digital Signatures" white paper concerning USB Tokens shows the user being prompted for a password.  Having a user specify a password isnt' going to work in my situation.  Is there anyway to pass the password (PIN) with the call to a SafeNet USB Token?

Answer (score 0):

Please read my white paper once more. In this paper, I'm showing different ways to sign a document with a USB token. When you use MSCAPI, it's evident that the user is prompted for a password because that's how it's implemented in the Windows OS. However, I also wrote [an example that uses PKCS#11](http://sourceforge.net/p/itext/code/HEAD/tree/tutorial/signatures/src/main/java/signatures/chapter4/C4_02_SignWithPKCS11USB.java). In this example, the password is fetched from a properties file; the user isn't prompted for it.

Comment: Hi Bruno, the link dosn't work and I did not find any SignWithPKCS11USB file in either Java or C# github repos.